# Extending a Protocol property to provide a default implementation in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

I have a protocol that I use for several enums which includes Swift 4.2's CaseIterable

```
    public protocol CycleValue: CaseIterable {

  /// Computed property that returns the next value of the property.
  var nextValue:Self { get }
}
```

One of my use cases for CycleValue is with a Theme property:

```
@objc public enum AppThemeAttributes: CycleValue  {

  case classic, darkMode // etc.

  public var nextValue: AppThemeAttributes {
    guard self != AppThemeAttributes.allCases.last else {
      return AppThemeAttributes.allCases.first!
    }

    return AppThemeAttributes(rawValue: self.rawValue + 1)!
  }
}
```

I have other uses cases; for example, button types. CaseIterable makes implementation of nextValue easy but the same for all types of CycleValue.

I would like to implement an extension to CycleValue that provides a default implementation for the nextValue property and avoid duplicating the code (i.e.: DRY!).

I've been struggling with PATs (Protocol Associated Types). Can't seem to get the syntax correct.

It should be possible, right? How can I provide a default implementation for nextValue to avoid ode duplication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution is to locate the current value in the `allCases` collection,
and the return the next element (or wrap around to the first element):

```
public protocol CycleValue: CaseIterable, Equatable {
    var nextValue: Self { get }
}

public extension CycleValue {
    var nextValue: Self {
        var idx = Self.allCases.index(of: self)!
        Self.allCases.formIndex(after: &idx)
        return idx == Self.allCases.endIndex ? Self.allCases.first! : Self.allCases[idx]
    }
}
```

(Note that both forced unwraps are safe!)
*Example:*

```
public enum AppThemeAttributes: CycleValue  {
    case classic, darkMode // etc.
}

let a = AppThemeAttributes.classic
print(a) // classic
let b = a.nextValue
print(b) // darkMode
let c = b.nextValue
print(c) // classic
```

The protocol must conform to `Equatable` for this to compile, but that
is not a real restriction: A `CaseIterable` protocol cannot have 
associated values, so that the compiler can always synthesize the
`Equatable` conformance.

Comment: @LeoDabus it would depend on where it's being used. I have an example where I declare a protocol in a framework, so I need to declare it public

Comment: @Martin's proposed solution is compact, clear and works for me. I was playing around with something similar but in the end I guess I was missing adopting Equatable. Nice! I've accepted it!

Comment: What about  `public extension CycleValue where  Self.AllCases: BidirectionalCollection  {
    var nextValue: Self {
        return Self.allCases[Self.allCases.index(Self.allCases.index(of: self)!, offsetBy: 1, limitedBy: Self.allCases.index(before: Self.allCases.endIndex)) ?? Self.allCases.startIndex]
    }
}`

Comment: and to make it complete add also the previous value `return Self.allCases[Self.allCases.index(Self.allCases.index(of: self)!, offsetBy: -1, limitedBy: Self.allCases.startIndex) ?? Self.allCases.index(before: Self.allCases.endIndex)]`

Comment: @Phantom59 you can also constrain the extension `public extension CycleValue where Self.AllCases.Element: Equatable  {`